# Не устанавливается время выполнения скрипта в yii2-queue

Tags: php, yii2, очередь

Использую yii2 и модуль queue. Закидываю в очередь команду, в консоли пишу `yii queue/listen`. Работа скрипта каждый раз падает через 5 минут с сообщением:

```
[-][-][-][error][yii\queue\Queue] [2890] <путь до job-а> (attempt: 1, PID: 9345) is finished with error: Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException: The process "'yii' 'queue/exec' '2890' '300' '1' '9345' '--color='" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

Поставил в код job-а в самое начало функции `execute` это:

```
set_time_limit(1800);
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');
```

не работает. видимо от того что процесс запускается в консоли, а в консоли такое не работает.

Меняю параметр `ttr` в конфиге `queue`:

```
'queue' => [
    'class' => \yii\queue\db\Queue::class,
    'db' => 'db', // компонент подключения к БД
    'tableName' => 'queue', // Имя таблицы
    'channel' => 'default', // Queue channel key
    'mutex' => \yii\mutex\MysqlMutex::class, // Mutex used to sync queries
    'ttr' => 60 * 60,
    'as log' => \yii\queue\LogBehavior::class,
    'on afterError' => function($event) {}
],
```

то есть `ttr` - 60*60 - 1 час. Но в ошибке сказано про 300 секунд. Откуда берётся эти 300 секунд и как их поменять?

Предвижу вопрос "а какое значение в php.ini?" - ответ: в php.ini значение max_execution_time вообще равен 30!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением в конфиг события:

```
'on beforePush' => function($event) {$event->ttr = 60 * 60;}
```

теперь подставляется нужный `ttr` и не падает через 5 минут. не совсем понятно зачем там тогда нужен параметр `ttr` если перед добавлением job-а в работу подставляется дефолтный `ttr` - 300

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите где какой конфиг у Вас стоит, т.к. время выполнения очереди записывается у вас скорее всего в в конфиге web.php т.е. там нужно ставить ttr 60 * 60, именно это значение попадает в конфиг очереди и бд, и потом уде берется из бд и передается косольному скрипту на выполнение.

Answer (score 1):

Конфиг надо править не web.php а console.php. параметр ttr в конфиге queue должен быть установлен в правильном конфиг-файле

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]